# I wiped everything on my phone with TWRP. What should I do?

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, twrp, htc

I wiped everything on my `HTC 10` device using TWRP (I checked everything). My device was rooted. Now how can I get the device working properly again? I think that I don't have anything on the device (and on the external sd) but the TWRP.

Comment: You need to flash a new ROM.

Answer (score 3):

With proper driver and ADB installed, sideload another ROM from your PC using `ADB sideload`, available in Advanced menu.

Comment: "With proper driver and ADB installed" can you, please, explain more or refer to a link about that? I am on macOS Sierra.

Comment: You need the USB driver from the manufacturer for ADB/fastboot to work. What method did you use when installing TWRP before this? If you did it from fastboot, then probably you already have these. If not... macOS might pose a problem, since HTC doesn't seem to have made a driver package for it.

Comment: I tried doing that with the command "adb sideload 2PS6IMG.zip" (where `2PS6IMG.zip` is a ROM I downloaded which is supposed to be stock ROM) but I got the message "cannot read zip file".

Comment: Make sure the filename and path is correct. Also, if I remember correctly, TWRP doesn't flash stock ROM packages (signature and update-binary problems). Find a stock-based custom one.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the HTC 10 has an microSD card slot. If you download a new ROM onto the card using another device (i.e. tablet) then insert it back into your phone, it should be able to reboot into a new install. I did the same thing on my Samsung Note II and this worked for me.

For information on how to install a new ROM, see:

http://www.howtogeek.com/162516/how-to-flash-your-nexus-s-or-any-other-android-device-with-a-new-rom/

http://lifehacker.com/how-to-flash-a-rom-to-your-android-phone-30885281

Comment: The links show how to install TWRP. The only thing I have on my device now is TWRP. They don't show how to install a new ROM.

Comment: You can use TWRP to add a new system onto your phone. I have edited the answer to better suite your needs.